# MySQL COUNT records before GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, select, count, group-by, distinct

I'm working on a simple query over two tables and I'm trying to count the number of records with the same ID I would have got if I didn't group them.
These are the tables:

### TABLE jobs

id  --  type  --  user_id  --  field_id

1  --  painting  --  53  --  12

2  --  reading  --  53  --  12

3  --  writing  --  53  --  12

### TABLE activities

id  --  is_test  --  user_id  --  field_id

7  --  Yes  --  53  --  12

8  --  No  --  53  --  12

With this query I get the single record that I want from the table `jobs` (painting) because I'm using the `GROUP BY` clause on the column `jobs.id`. If I didn't use the GROUP BY, I would get 2 records because there are 2 matching activities for the same `user_id` and `field_id`.

```
SELECT `jobs`.*,`activities`.`is_test` 
FROM `jobs` 
LEFT JOIN `activities` ON `activities`.`user_id`=`jobs`.`user_id` 
WHERE `jobs`.`field_id`=12 AND `activities`.`field_id`=12 AND `jobs`.`type`='painting' AND `jobs`.`user_id`=53 
GROUP BY `jobs`.`id` 
ORDER BY `jobs`.`id` DESC;
```

What I'm trying to do is to fetch another column containing the actual number of matching records in the table `activities`. Basically I want to get 2 as count of records in `activities` with the same `user_id` and `field_id`.

I have tried to select the new column like this:

```
SELECT `jobs`.*,`activities`.`is_test`, COUNT(DISTINCT `jobs`.`id`) AS `tot_act`
```

but this obviously returns 1 rather than 2 for the new column `tot_act`. Making it count the field `activities.is_test` did not work either.

I was **trying to avoid a sub-select**.

Please do not pay attention to the column `activities.is_test`, I don't care to see if it's set to Yes or No, I just want to count that there is a matching record for Yes and one for No so 2 records in total if I don't group them. **2 is the value I'm trying to retrieve** as a new column.

Any ideas will be much appreciated!

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are trying to do? There is a lot of information here and I think your request is stuck somewhere in the middle of all of it.

Comment: Firstly, don't use a `select jobs.*` and a group by. MySQL may allow you to select columns that aren't part of the aggregation or group by, but not many others do. Also, you say that you get 1 record with your first query because you are grouping on `jobs.id`. I don't see how this is possible according to your sample data as you are selecting 2 rows with 2 different id's

Comment: Sorry, I will try to clarify it. Given the query I'm using, I want to retrieve all the records of the table `jobs` with ID 1 because the type is `painting`. I then want one of the two matching columns `is_test` in the table `activities` as I don't care which record it is as long as the `user_id` and `field_id` are matching. Finally I want to get a count-column as 2 because 2 are the matching records in the table `activities`. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify your statement about the `is_test` column. Do you want to show a column that says `yes` or `no` and you don't care which column it is?

Comment: @Lock: thank you, I don't care to know whether the column `is_test` is Yes or No, I just want to know that there are 2 records. Going to try your solution soon. Thanks again

Comment: `Count(*)` should do it. Why do you insist on adding a `Distinct` on your count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query doesn't make any sense. Group by only has meaning combined with an aggregate function in the output columns (select clause).

The where filter on activities.field_id is (expensively) converting the left join into an inner join.

I also suspect your schema is not normalised.

> to fetch another column containing the actual number of matching records in the table activities

```
SELECT `jobs`.id, jobs.type, jobs.user_id, 
  Jobs.field_id,`activities`.`is_test`, 
  SUM(IF(activities.id IS NULL, 0,1)) 
FROM `jobs` 
 LEFT JOIN `activities` 
 ON `activities`.`user_id`=`jobs`.`user_id` 
 AND activities.field_id=12
WHERE `jobs`.`field_id`=12 
 AND `jobs`.`type`='painting' 
 AND `jobs`.`user_id`=53 
GROUP BY `jobs`.id, jobs.type, jobs.user_id, 
  Jobs.field_id,`activities`.`is_test`
ORDER BY `jobs`.`id` DESC;
```

Comment: thank you this works fine. The other solutions were not letting me fetch the is_test field. My example of 'Yes' / 'No' was confusing. Thanks for letting me notice that the field_id filter in the where clause was converting the left join into an inner join.

Answer (score 1):

COUNT() increments by 1 for each NON NULL value it encounters.

In your case you want the count of rows from the activities table, not the jobs table.

```
SELECT
      jobs.id
    , jobs.type
    , jobs.user_id
    , Jobs.field_id
    , COUNT(activities.id) activity_count
FROM jobs
      LEFT JOIN activities ON jobs.user_id = activities.user_id
                  AND activities.field_id = 12
WHERE jobs.field_id = 12
      AND jobs.type = 'painting'
      AND jobs.user_id = 53
GROUP BY
      jobs.id
    , jobs.type
    , jobs.user_id
    , Jobs.field_id
ORDER BY
      jobs.id DESC;
```

from your sample data that query produces this result:

```
| id |     type | user_id | field_id | activity_count |
|----|----------|---------|----------|----------------|
|  1 | painting |      53 |       12 |              2 |
```

Note however that if you include activity.is_test in the select and grouping clauses then you will not get a count of 2.

see [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a508e/2)

Comment: Thank you, this works fine too but it won't let me fetch the is_test field that I needed.

Comment: as said, if you include activities.is_test in the select and group by clauses the count will not be 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  `jobs`.id,
  `jobs`.type,
  `jobs`.user_id,
  `jobs`.field_id,
  count(1) as activities_count,
  max(`activities`.is_test) as is_test
FROM
  `jobs`
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `activities` ON
  `activities`.user_id = `jobs`.user_id
  AND `activities`.field_id = `jobs`.field_id
WHERE
  `jobs`.field_id = 12
  AND `jobs`.type = 'painting'
  AND `jobs`.user_id = 53
GROUP BY
  `jobs`.id,
  `jobs`.type,
  `jobs`.user_id,
  `jobs`.field_id
```